# Generics and anonymous type

Tags: c#, generics

I understood,normally generics is for compile time safe and allow us to keep strongly typed collection.Then how do generic allow us to store anonymous types like

```
List<object> TestList = new List<object>();
TestList.Add(new { id = 7, Name = "JonSkeet" });
TestList.Add(new { id = 11, Name = "Marc Gravell" });
TestList.Add(new { id = 31, Name = "Jason" });
```

Comment: @nettguy - strange you used members from here to fill your list.

Comment: Even anonymous types derive from `Object`.

Comment: Clarification: Everything excluding pointer types is convertible to object. Not everything actually derives from object. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works because `object` is the root type of all instances in .Net.  Hence anything expression can be used for a location expecting an `object` because they all meet the basic contract of `System.object`.

For example the following is completely legal.

```
List<object> TestList = new List<object>();
TestList.Add(new { id = 7, Name = "JonSkeet" });
TestList.Add("Foo");
TestList.Add(42);
```

Comment: How would you cast the first item back out given that you don't have a declared type you can reference?

Answer (score 9):

Others already explained why your code works - your example is strongly typed, because everything is an object, but that means that it's not very useful. You cannot take elements from the list and access for example their `Name` property, because they are just object, so this cannot work in general.

However, it is possible to create a strongly typed `List` of anonymous types - it just needs to be done using a small utility method like this:

```
static List<T> CreateList<T>(params T[] items) {
  return items.ToList();
}
```

The problem is that you can't call a constructor without providing the name of the type. When calling a method, C# can infer the type parameter, so you can write this:

```
var testList = CreateList(
  new { id = 7, Name = "JonSkeet" },
  new { id = 11, Name = "Marc Gravell" });
testList.Add(new { id = 31, Name = "Jason" });
```

This is perfectly type-safe and you can for example write `testList[0].Name` to get the name of the first person. If you try writing something like `testList.Add(42)`, you'll get a compile-time error, because the list is strongly typed to contain only anonymous types with `id` and `Name` properties.

Comment: +1 Fascinating, and eloquently said. I do find myself wondering what real-world scenario would you want to be using lists of "anonymous objects" other than as a form of "obfuscating" the code. Another "aha" moment waiting there, I'm sure :)

Comment: @BillW: It's a convenience thing; it saves you from having to define your own little helper type. Now that there is a standard Tuple type in the framework, the usage case for jumping through hoops to make lists of anonymous type is much weaker.

Comment: Incidentally, this technique is often called "cast by example". If you search for that phrase on SO you'll find a number of questions where people attempt to build anonymous-typed lists, dictionaries, and so on.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Yes, I discovered the trick independently some time ago: http://tomasp.net/articles/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx :-)

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Actually, I thought that "cast by example" refers only to the unsafe use (as in my article). The code here (to create lists/dictionaries/etc.) is fully type-safe - it is just simulating type inference for constructors (which isn't supported) using a method call... (BTW: Adding type inference for constructor calls would be nice!)

Comment: @Tomas: I guess that adding that kind of type inference would require inference on the return type. Not sure how hard that is to add to the language, but I suppose there's something bad/difficult about it because it was left out so far.

Comment: @Martinho: It shouldn't be difficult (of course, C# is more complex than most of the people expect, but still...). You can already omit type parameters on method calls - e.g. `a.Foo(1)` instead of `a.Foo<int>(1)`. I'm asking for similar thing for constructors - something like `new List<?> { 1, 2, 3 }` instead of `new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }`. (the `?` would be a special symbol - something like `var`).

Comment: @Tomas: yes, for those examples it would work and it would be nice, but how would you do type inference on `var foo = new List<?>()`? Possible? No doubt. F# does it, Haskell does it. Worth the C# team's effort? I don't know. I'm not sure they would be happy shipping a feature that covers half the cases, especially when calling default constructors can be rather common :(

Comment: @Martinho: I wouldn't allow that - type inference in C# works in the scope of expressions only. F# or Haskell use very different approach. My case is actually questionable, because it uses inference based on the `Add` method (used by object initializers) and not the constructor directly, so that would require some effort. I guess it's not all that useful, but it would be nice to have :-).

Answer (score 6):

Because everything is (or can be boxed into) an `object`, and that's a `List` of `object`s.

Comment: To be pedantic, it should say 'or can be **converted** into'.