# Anonymous object as generic type

Tags: c#, generics, hierarchy, anonymous-objects

I have the following generic interface:

```cs
public interface IDatabaseEntity<out T>
{
    public T GetKey();
}
```

Now, I define several entities which all implement this interface. An example:

```cs
public class Player : IDatabaseEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // Other fields...

    public Guid GetKey() => Id; // Implement the interface
}
```

This all works fine, but now I have an entity which is uniquely defined by multiple fields. Thus, I need something of the following:

```cs
public class SessionRecord : IDatabaseEntity<{Guid GameId; Guid PlayerId; DateTimeOffset StartDate}>
{
    public Guid            GameId    { get; set; }
    public Guid            PlayerId  { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset  StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? EndTime   { get; set; }


    public object GetKey() => new { GameId, PlayerId, StartTime }; // Implement the interface
}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561885/15746803), I believe that something like this might be possible, as the compiler can thus differentiate between an 'object' and an anonymous type.

How can I make a method in my interface return an anonymous object, as well as Guids or strings, etc?

Comment: Have you considered using a tuple type instead of an anonymous type?

Comment: I think you're confusing a list of objects against an dynamic object. As Jon said, a Tuple or alike would make a lot more sense here.

Comment: Well I will be damned. Thanks guys! I still wonder though if this is possible, so I will leave my question open.

Answer (score 2):

would it be great to create a model on that like

```
 public class TestModel {
    public Guid GameId;
    public Guid PlayerId;
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate;
}
```

and use it like

```
public class SessionRecord : IDatabaseEntity<TestModel>
{
    public Guid            GameId    { get; set; }
    public Guid            PlayerId  { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset  StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? EndTime   { get; set; }


    public TestModel GetKey() => new TestModel(); // Implement the interface
}
```

Edit 18:63

```
public class SessionRecord : IDatabaseEntity<object>
{
    public Guid            GameId    { get; set; }
    public Guid            PlayerId  { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset  StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? EndTime   { get; set; }


    public object GetKey() => new { GameId, PlayerId, StartTime }; // Implement the interface
}
```

Comment: In general this would be the answer, but for some niche reason I really require the object to be passable to EFCore as an ``id`` with which I can uniquely identify a database entity. Classes or other wrappers won't work there